# uninitialized constant [Active Admin]

Tags: activeadmin

I have error message **"uninitialized constant Slideapp::Appinfos"**

My database have 2 table is appinfo and slideapp.This is code in my model

```
class Appinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :slideapps
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :slideapps 
end

class Slideapp < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :appinfos
end
```

**How do I fix this problem ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unrelated to ActiveAdmin.

Your `belongs_to` should use the singular form of Appinfo:

```
class Slideapp < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :appinfo # <= use of singular Appinfo
end
```

As it is now Rails is trying to autoload the class `Appinfos`, which doesn't exist.